# Can't access port 7474 across Rackspace cloud servers

Tags: networking, neo4j, port, rackspace-cloud, devops

I've setup neo4j on port 7474 on a Rackspace cloud server. I want to access this server from another Rackspace cloud server (appserver) but the connection is refused.

I've tried enabling access for the appserver to port 7474 on the neo4j server using ufw:

> > sudo ufw allow from 22.234.298.297 to any port 7474

I can see this rule when I run 'ufw staus' but it doesn't seem to make any difference when I try to connect to the appserver. I can ssh between these two servers.

How do I open port 7474 between cloud servers on Rackspace?

*(my apologies for this very basic question but rackspace support are not helping and I cant find rackspace specific information on this)*

Comment: Is it possible you need a `ufw` command on the other server to allow the outbound connection?

Comment: Is it possible your machines have more than one address?  For example, one that is visible to the outside world and one that is used internal to Rackspace?

Comment: Thanks John. Yes, they have two addresses, one internal and one external. I've added rules for both, just to be sure. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried changing which address you appserver tries to connect to?

Comment: Since ssh is working for you, you might try adding `-v` to your `ssh` command (`ssh -v ...`) and looking through the output for the `Connecting to` line to see which address ssh is using which is working.

Comment: the default for neo4j is to listen to localhost. what IP did you put as value for org.neo4j.server.webserver.address in your neo4j-server.properties?

Comment: @manonthemat Thanks! org.neo4j.server.webserver was still set to localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad, we could solve the problem (see comments on the question).

It so happens that Neo4j accepts only connections from localhost per default. When trying to gain access to Neo4j via REST API from an app server within the same network, one has to configure the Neo4j server to open up.

The `neo4j-server.properties` configuration file has a configuration key with `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address`. You have a couple of options here.

1. Grant app servers in the same local network to consume the Neo4j REST API
2. Grant everybody access and let the firewall handle it

For the first case, use the local ip address of the machine where Neo4j is running. Let's say your machines are connected via a private class C network. The machine with Neo4j has an ip *192.168.1.4* - that's the ip you want to enter as the value in `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address`, so your app server running in the same network with maybe an ip of *192.168.1.5* can make network requests that are being answered by the Neo4j web server.

For the second case, you enter *0.0.0.0* as value for `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address` to denote that you want to accept connections on all available ip addresses on that machine. In that case you want to set up your firewall to handle permissions who can talk to the server and who doesn't - even with authentication enabled.

**Extra**
In a production environment that requires high availability, one can use Neo4j's enterprise edition with a high availability cluster in a master-slave setting. I've used in with one master and two slaves. I configured the Neo4j servers that they can only be accessed from the proxy server that routes writing cypher queries to the master, and reading queries to the slaves. The proxy itself had a hardware firewall on it to ensure only specific app servers within the network have access to the Neo4j database.